# numpy matrix MemoryError only on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am getting a MemoryError when creating a large matrix in numpy using the following statement.

`V = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape = (X_design.shape[0], X_design.shape[0])))`

This matrix is being created to store a covariance matrix.

`X_design.shape[0] = ~50,000`

I know this is a large matrix but this has worked on a OSX machines with 8 and 16gigs of ram, and a windows 10 machine with 16 gigs of ram. We are trying to run this code on a Windows 7 machine with 16 gigs of ram and continue to get the MemoryError.

Is there a way to get this to work on a Windows 7 machine? Is there something about Windows 7 that is causing this error?

All tests have been done using 64bit Python.

We have tried rebooting and limiting the number of applications open, we have also recreated the error on a different windows 7 machine.

Thanks Michael

Comment: Are you sure you have 64-bit NumPy?

Comment: I executed the following code to see if I have 64 bit numpy 


`import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo`
`sysinfo.platform_bits`

and result is `64`.  So I think that means I have 64bit numpy.

Comment: This single line tries to allocate about 40 GB of memory, which obviously doesn't fit in the physical RAM. Maybe the difference is that Windows 10 is able to [compress things in memory](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ram-compression-improves-memory-responsiveness-windows-10/). It could also be due to different settings for the page file size.

Comment: @user7138814 that is interesting - that may be why the Win10 machine is working. I think this is an issue with Virtual Memory. The OSX machines (4gig of ram - 16gig of ram) are able to complete because the dump to disk automatically, the Win7 machine can complete if a specify a page file size of ~ 40gigs.